# Windows сам перезагружается

Tags: windows-10

Часто бывает такое что ПК сам собой уходит в перезагрузку.
И не такую как от кнопки перезагрузить, а такую как будто нажали кнопку ресет.
Довольно часто после этой перезагрузки происходит обновление windows(возможно из за обновления).
Что можно попробовать сделать и как понять в чем причина таких перезагрузок ?
Windows 10
Это проблема появилась после апдейта (там еще вот такая штука была, как на скрине)
[image]

Comment: Вы сам процесс перезагрузки наблюдали лично или просто позже подходили к компу и обнаруживали, что он когда-то перезагрузился?

Comment: Я работал за компом и тут он сам вырубился моментально (будто кнопка ресет) и начал загружатся после чего началось обновление.
Так уже не 1 раз но не всегда обнова

Answer (score 1):

Если он выключается после некоторого времени работы, то скорее всего проблема в перегреве. Разберите комп и почистите кулер и всю систему охлаждения.
А также если комп не новый рекомендую приобрести доп охлаждение или заменить кулер.

Comment: Ну у меня были перегревы...
Тогда ПК выключается и больше не включается.
А сейчас он перезагружается...

Comment: Ну ты как хочешь, а я эту проблему со своим компом именно так и решил.